# nginx creating url segment to parameter

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, config

So I'm not sure if the topic name is correct so here is, what I want to do...

I have an URL like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/website_folder/userdata/account
```

Now I'm looking for a nginx config which converts my given url to s.th like

```
index.php?url=userdata/account
```

for

```
location /website_folder/ { }
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
```

I realy hope there is a solution out there.

Comment: Use a `rewrite` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tested a lot of options and stuff so I ended with this:

```
    location /website_folder/ {
        if (!-d $request_filename){
            set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename){
            set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
        }
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
        }
        if ($rule_0 = "321"){
            rewrite ^/website_folder/(.+)$ /website_folder/index.php?url=$1 last;
        }
    }
```

perhaps there is a better option to avoid the if statements but... it works